# Python client write to Java's writeUTF method

Tags: java, python, sockets, client, server

I have the following code snippet for a **Java** server that can't be changed:

```
 ....
 while(true){
 try {
            System.out.println("Will listen . . .");
            instruction = this.dis.readUTF();  // Socket's dataInputStream
            System.out.println("Got instruction: " + instruction);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ServerThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

  ....
 } // end while(true)
```

And I have the following client code for **python**:

```
.... 
self.socket.send(b"GET~CARD\n")
print self.socket.recv(1024)
....
```

The problem that I'm facing is that I can get  the client to send information to the server but the server won't stop listening, so it stays on the blocking call `this.dis.readUTF();`.

As you can see I tried using the `\n` character at the end of the string but it stays listening. Does anybody knows how to write from a python client to a java server using `readUTF()`?

Comment: Try making use of Unicode string literals, `u"GET~CARD"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the docs for the `readUTF` function [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#readUTF())

Primarily, this stands out

> First, two bytes are read and used to construct an unsigned 16-bit
>   integer in exactly the manner of the readUnsignedShort method . This
>   integer value is called the UTF length and specifies the number of
>   additional bytes to be read. These bytes are then converted to
>   characters by considering them in groups. The length of each group is
>   computed from the value of the first byte of the group. The byte
>   following a group, if any, is the first byte of the next group.

Try something like this in your python code

```
import struct
message = u"GET~CARD\n"
size = len(message)
...
sock.send(struct.pack("!H", size))
sock.send(message)
```

Comment: This is just what I was looking for! Just used `sock.send` instead of `sock.write` and everything worked like a charm!

Thanks!